# jQuery datepicker having trouble in IE8?

Tags: jquery, datepicker

i did see a couple of similar threads, but later they turned out to be different issues...mine seems a browser specific problem surely because my datepicker works fine in Firefox, but certainly not in IE8.
[Here is my original problem and the source code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5450783/textfield-not-displaying-date-picked-from-jquery-datepicker-in-mvc3)

I updated my datepicker to jQuery UI Datepicker 1.8.11...still it just doesn't work in IE 8! The date-picker pops up just fine, but no event fires from it. I mean no click...nothing happens...

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you ever happen to figure out your issue on this? I was having the exact same problem and it turned out that our test environment had the security settings on high, meaning things like Active Scripting were disabled.

Comment: Upvoting question because I have a similar problem.  IE 8 (not 7 or 9) gives an error as the calendar begins to draw "Can't move focus on control because it is invisible, not enabled, or of a type that does not accept the focus."  The element is a hidden input type in my case because I don't actually have a visible date input widget.

Answer (score 3):

Hey I don't know if you have solved that problem yet, however the problem is with any added attributes. Especially if you are using:

```
yearRange: '-100:+10'
```

for example ...

This is how you resolve the issue: copied from http://satish.name/?p=19

jQuery datepicker adds a new attribute to the DOM element in IE. if you try to add a new DOM element dynamically copying from an existing element the datepicker will not work in IE as the newly added DOM element refers to the old jQuery attribute. One way to fix this is to delete the attribute and then instantiate the datepicker class on the element. See the following code for the fix.

```
//newDiv is the new added dom element with innerHTML
jQuery("#newDiv").find(".datePicker").each(function() {
    //removing jquery added attribute as this is causing the dynamically
    // added DOM elem referring old DOM element from it is copied.
    if (jQuery.browser.msie) {
        var jqaddedattr;
        jQuery(this.attributes).each(function() {
            if (this.name.search(/jQuery/) != -1) {
                jqaddedattr = this;
            }
        });
        if (jqaddedattr) {
            jQuery(this).removeAttr(jqaddedattr.name);
        }
    }
    jQuery(this).datepicker({yearRange: '-100:+10', changeFirstDay:false}).val("").trigger('change');
})
```

cheers

Answer (score 2):

This jsFiddle contains the most basic code to get a jQuery UI datepicker working on an `<input type="text" />` element.

http://jsfiddle.net/rbwh7/2/

I've confirmed that this runs on IE8, Chrome, Firefox.

Can you test this as see if this works for you?

Comment: pitts...thx for that.. it works like a charm in firefox and chrome..  not in ie8.. by the way, even the url jsfiddle.net/rbwh7/2 do not open correctly in ie8..the editor dont show up.  and oh..does it matter that i am trying this out on win server 2008?

Comment: @hillary: I can't imagine that it would (re. Server 2008). That's very strange because my IE8 doesn't have an issue. could it be some kind of security setting in IE (grasping at straws)?

Comment: @alastair..not sure. i will let you know if I figure out..  i have left that issue there and moved onto creating a date-range .. trying to bind the date in format ..without the time being displayed!

Comment: @alastair..thx for the link.. its now my playground..as soon as i have 25pts..i will vote it up :)

Answer (score 2):

This is further information rather than an answer but unfortunately it was too long to add as a comment.

The issue I see is that the DatePicker is displayed correctly but none of its events fire correctly (e.g. clicking dates or the month navigation does nothing).

I have narrowed this issue down to a particular build of IE8 (v8.0.7600.16385) running on Windows 2008 R2 x64. We have other VMs on the same OS but with different builds of IE8 and this problem does not occur. We have not seen the issue on IE8 running on Windows XP, Vista, 2003 or 7. It also works fine in Firefox and Chrome.

I have tried the fix referenced by mahatmanich but this did not resolve the issue (although we do not use the yearRange option).

I have also fully updated Windows (excluding IE9) but this did not update the IE8 version number or fix the issue.

Finally I updated jQuery to 1.7.1 and jQuery UI to 1.8.17 but neither update resolved the problem.

Does anyone have any other ideas or information?

Comment: I am also seeing this issue in Windows 2008 R2 SP1 64 bit. The IE version is 8.0.7601.17514.

Answer (score 1):

I am now using jQuery DateTimePicker plugin v2.2.5. When it runs on IE8, the date-picker had no response when I was clicking on td elements of day.The click event seemed not to be fired.
Then I went to console ,I found runtime error of datepicker script. A variable was null ,when others calling the function of it. After debug I found the variable was set to null in the follow codes.(I just set validateOnBlur to false in options to resolve the issue..)

```
if( options.validateOnBlur ) {
    input.off('blur.xdsoft')
    .on('blur.xdsoft', function() {
        if( options.allowBlank && !$.trim($(this).val()).length ) {
            $(this).val(null);
            //***************************************************
            // After running of the following line, the variable 
            //_xdsoft_datetime.currentTime was setting to null.
            // It seemed that the order of events fired not as 
            //expected.Valedate runned before the selected day value sets to input..
            // So I just set validateOnBlur to false in options to resolve the issue..
            datetimepicker.data('xdsoft_datetime').empty();
        }else if( !Date.parseDate( $(this).val(), options.format ) ) {
            $(this).val((_xdsoft_datetime.now()).dateFormat( options.format ));
            datetimepicker.data('xdsoft_datetime').setCurrentTime($(this).val());
        }
        else{
            datetimepicker.data('xdsoft_datetime').setCurrentTime($(this).val());
        }
        datetimepicker.trigger('changedatetime.xdsoft');
   });
}
```

Comment: I changed datetimepicker.data('xdsoft_datetime').empty(); to datetimepicker.data('xdsoft_datetime').setCurrentTime(''); and it works. Or you can set validateOnBlur to false

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue. In my case, I had to click in the datetimepicker pop-up box once to get the focus and a second time to get the actual event fired in IE8.

Adding the following option when declaring the datetimepicker options solved my problem:

```
validateOnBlur: false
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I couldn't change the month or the year, when it was open a datetimepicker over a jquery dialog.

I can fix this problem adding a onShow listener that make focus over another input.
This is my source code:

```
$(".date").datetimepicker({
    dayOfWeekStart : 1,
    timepicker : false,
    scrollMonth : false,
    scrollInput : false,
    format : 'd/m/Y',
    formatDate : 'd/m/Y',
    lang : 'es',
    onShow : function() {
        $('#anotherInput').focus();
    },
});
```