# Jquery Datepicker events not fired on IE8

Tags: c#, jquery, internet-explorer-8

Date picker control events using jquery doesnot work on **IE8** .
My environment is IE version: 8.0.7601.17514
Machine : **64bit**
Operating system : **windows 7**
Jquery version : **jquery-1.7.1.js**
Jquery UI Version :jquery-ui-1.8.20.js

Code Block :

```
@Html.TextBox("txt1")
```

Jquery script:

```
$("#txt1").datepicker({
       changeMonth: true,
       changeYear: true                         
});
```

Jquery script is inside Document ready

However the same code works on **IE9 .**
Did anyone else experience the same problem

Comment: Can you post your page doctype?

Comment: page document type is .cshtml, am creating a MVC4 application

Answer (score 0):

Accordingly with [jQuery datepicker having trouble in IE8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5454489/jquery-datepicker-having-trouble-in-ie8), you have to upgrade the jquery version to 1.8 or above.

Also read this http://forums.asp.net/t/1626097.aspx/1

Comment: changed the JQuery from jquery-1.7.1.js to jquery-1.10.2.js , its not working

Comment: Can you provide me a part of ASP.NET code and a part of js code ? Means more information than you provided.

Comment: i'm creating an mvc4 application so my cshtml code is @Html.TextBox("txt1") and my jquery text : $("#txt1").datepicker({
       changeMonth: true,
       changeYear: true      Am using the jquery scripts       jquery-1.7.1.js Jquery UI Version :jquery-ui-1.8.20.js            
});